# morphism of a variety onto affine space with an infinite fiber

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

There is the following geometric interpretation of Noether's normalization theorem:

> Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional affine variety. Then there is a surjective morphism $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{A}^n$ with finite fibers, i.e. $|\varphi^{-1}(p)| < \infty$ for all $p \in \mathbb{A}^n$.

I wonder if there could be also a surjective morphism $X \to \mathbb{A}^n$ with an infinite fiber. Can you name some example?

Thank you in advance!

**Added later:** After writing this question I realized that a fiber is an intersection of $n$ hypersurfaces of $X$ so it is likely that their intersection is zero-dimensional and hence finite. Is this true? In this case how can we show that the dimension actually drops with each intersection, i.e. why are the irreducible components of the intersection of the first $i$ hypersurfaces not contained in the ($i+1$)-th one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the blowup of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at a point $p$; this gives a birational morphism $\mbox{Bl}_p(\mathbb{A}^2)\to\mathbb{A}^2$ whose fiber over $p$ is infinite.

**Edit:** For an affine example, consider $\phi:\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{A}^2$ where $(x,y)\mapsto(xy,x+x^2+xy)$. If $(z_0,w_0)\in\mathbb{A}^2$ and $x_0$ is a root of $x^2+x=w_0-z_0$ ($x_0\neq0$ when $z_0=w_0$), then $\phi(x_0,z_0/x_0)=(z_0,w_0)$. Over $(0,0)$, however, we get the fiber $\{(0,y):y\in k\}\cup\{(-1,0)\}$.

Comment: The OP did (perhaps) ask for $X$ to be _affine_, though...

Comment: Thank you very much! As Asal said I am mainly interested in the affine case, but this example is also very interesting! Just for clarification: The canonical map $\mathrm{Bl}_p(\mathbb{A}^2) \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is a surjective morphism in the ordinary sense which additionally induces a birational morphism, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
@AsalBeagDubh, you're absolutely right, I edited my answer.

Comment: I already gave +1, but morally I give another +1.